# c++ template short circuit logic AND (&&)

Tags: c++, templates, short-circuiting

I've been told that **logic AND** (`&&`) in template doesn't work, so I want to use template specialization to achive it.

My test code like follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool b1, bool b2>
constexpr static bool andVal = false;

// template specialization
template <bool b2>
constexpr static bool andVal<true, b2> = b2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << andVal<1, 1> << std::endl;
  std::cout << andVal<0, 1> << std::endl;
  std::cout << andVal<0, 0> << std::endl;
  std::cout << andVal<1, 0> << std::endl; // this line will cause compilation error
  return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the code, error occured like this:

```
/tmp/ccaqDdfO.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccaqDdfO.s:369: Error: symbol `_ZL6andVal' is already defined
```

If I comment the last line test code `std::cout << andVal<1, 1> << std::endl;`, the compilation will success and the test result is correct.

What's wrong with the template function? and why it is already defined?

Any reply will be appreciated!

Comment: Your code compiles fine. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/VDUUAe). Which compiler and C++ version do you use?

Comment: "I've been told that logic AND (&&) in template doesn't work" not clear what you mean. Maybe you refer to the fact that in `condition1<T> && condition2<T>` the second condition has to be a valid expression even if the first is `true`. Thats however not really a special case for templates

Comment: works fine for me with gcc 8.3.

Comment: @NutCracker My compiler is gcc 5.4, I use `g++ -c -std=c++14 -O0 -g3 -o test.o test.cpp` command to compile it, and get the error message.

Comment: @WholeYu it is compiled successfully with GCC 5.4 also. I think you have problem elsewhere in your code

Comment: @NutCracker I'm so sorry! The last line code I post here is wrong, and I have modified now. The error will occure now, please try it again.

Comment: It blows up godbolt nicely as well, looks like you need at least version 6.4

Comment: need c++14 / newer. you forget to isolate it to test it? it gets mingled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is fine. This is a bug in gcc versions 5.4 through 6.1: [template specialization compile error](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71875). You happen to be on the bottom edge of the bugged version range.